# Creating HTML with javascript interrupts touch listener

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, touch

I am using threejs, but this is probably not related to threejs.

I have a touch listener:

> document.addEventListener('touchend', handleTouchEnd, {passive:
> false});

works fine. I am dynamicly creating some html elements like a text based on what user is doing, but when the html is created while user is touching screen, the touchend is not register at all. Ie nothing fires.
So it seems that when html is created on fly with javascript, for some reason the touch events are interrupted, perhaps the touch is removed in some way or something like that.
After user taps again, events fire as expected again. Ie the events get interrupted only in the moment when html is created and touch events are for whatever reason not working.

I was not able to figure out what is happening. Cancel event is not firing either.

Edit: User is touching screen to walk, so during this time, html element gets created with javascript and when user lifts finger to stop walking ( whether it's in half second or in 5 seconds ), the touch end event is not fired.

Comment: @Teemu Should have clarified, user is touching screen to walk, so it happens during that time he is touching screen continuously. Will Edit.